# How do I initialize a Set in Java?

Tags: java, collections, initialization, set

This is fine...

```
public class someClass {
   private Set<Element> pre;

   public void someMethod() {
      pre.add(new Element());
   }
}
```

But this isn't...

```
public class someClass {

    public void someMethod() {
       Set<Element> pre;
       pre.add(new Element());
    }
}
```

What's the correct syntax for the latter case without just turning it into the former?

Comment: Neither is _fine_. One will simply fail later.

Comment: You need to pass argument in `Set` construct as `private Set<Element> pre = new HashSet<Element>(elementObject);`

Answer (score 12):

In both cases you are missing the initialization of the `Set`, but in the first case it's initialized to `null` by default, so the code will compile, but will throw a `NullPointerException` when you try to add something to the `Set`. In the second case, the code won't even compile, since local variables must be assigned a value before being accessed.

You should fix both examples to

```
private Set<Element> pre = new HashSet<Element>();
```

and

```
Set<Element> pre = new HashSet<Element>();
```

Of course, in the second example, the `Set` is local to `someMethod()`, so there's no point in this code (you are creating a local `Set` which you are never using).

`HashSet` is one implementation of `Set` you can use. There are others. And if your know in advance the number of distinct elements that would be added to the `Set`, you can specify that number when constructing the `Set`. It would improve the `Set`'s performance, since it wouldn't need to be re-sized.

```
private Set<Element> pre = new HashSet<Element>(someInitialSize);
```

Comment: "HashSet cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: @Micromancer You should import it - `import java.util.HashSet;`.